# Is a "midnight" closing date accidentally or intentionally misleading?

Tags: applications, deadlines

A disturbing proportion of job adverts seem to say something along the lines of:

> Applications close at midnight on [date]

Strictly, that means that any applications received during the day in question will NOT be accepted. Often, I think this is a mistake, and they actually mean that applications WILL be accepted up to and including 11:59pm on [date]. (Indeed, the more helpful examples state 11:59pm as the time that applications close, for the avoidance of doubt).

Of course, the natural response from an applicant is to make sure the application is submitted before [date] anyway, so it becomes a non-issue. 
Nonetheless, the ambiguity always irritates me . And it got me thinking: **would a recruiter ever stick to the strictly correct interpretation of a "midnight" deadline, and use this as a deliberate tactic to weed out applicants who lack attention to detail and have poor time-management?**

[This is intended as a general question, but if it needs narrowing down, my particular experience is of applying for academic and teaching jobs in the field of biology.]

Comment: Really, a tactic to weed out applicants.  Uh, they want applicants.

Comment: See also [How should “midnight on…” be interpreted?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6459/how-should-midnight-on-be-interpreted).

Comment: This is not a tactic. People who use '11:59pm' or '23:59:59' or something like that are trying hard to make it clear when the deadline is. Others probably just didn't think about it too deeply. People also sometimes get confused at the usage of '12:00pm' and '12:00am' and sometimes 'noon' and 'midnight' are suggested as alternatives.

Comment: @Paparazzi What they want is the single best candidate for the job. The entire process is about narrowing down the list of applicants until they've found the right one. My understanding is that many recruiters receive a huge volume of applications and need an efficient way to whittle them down. I don't think "you failed to understand 'midnight' correctly" is any more or less plausible as a reason for crossing someone off the list than "you misspelled a word on your CV".

Comment: @Brandin I agree, before 12:00am would Sound to me before noon instead of before midnight. I am so happy we dont use am and pm here :)

Comment: Would a recruiter use this tactic to weed people out? Maybe, who knows, though many would find that tactic ridiculous, arbitrary, and not at all useful. There is no general answer to this, and it will completely vary from recruiter to recruiter.

Comment: Pretty sure I read it here that one particular recruiter would take half the applications and throw them away without a single look, his rationale being that he wouldn't want to hire someone unlucky. This is a brilliant example of both the unpredicatability of the application process, and a self-fulfilling prophecy.

Comment: They can use any closing date they want and they will use midnight to narrow the field?  The is just silly.

Comment: @Brandin noon is 12:00m   AM stands for ante-meridian PM stands for post-meridian  Noon is the meridian.  However, given the fact that people are woefully ignorant these days, 12:00m would likely be misinterpreted as midnight.  You just can't win

Comment: @user2390246 misspelling a word on your CV is a clear error on your part, and related to a relevant skill for many jobs.  Understanding an ambiguous statement the "wrong" way is not a clear error on the part of the applicant.

Comment: Ah, technically right: the best kind of right. Even if your interpretation of midnight wasn't different from how any sane person would see it, the question is entirely pointless. Virtually no candidates will wait until this late into the process. Any that do or who learn about the position late in the process can still apply and in most cases they will still be considered. VTC as opinion-based since the question posed has no useful answer.

Comment: @RichardU The convention is to take noon as PM when one must write either AM or PM. If you think about it, having a moment of time that is exactly on the meridian is extremely unlikely. Even 12:00 noon + 0.001 ms is still post meridian.

Comment: @Brandin I'm aware of that.  The reason for that convention is that so few people understood the old one.

Comment: @Lilienthal I strongly believe I am a sane person... As I understand it, midnight is 0000, not 2400, so comes at the start rather than the end of the day. Clearly this is not as universally accepted as I thought (which is good to know). Regardless, I feel like piecing together information from the various comments and answers has given me a useful answer: almost anything is possible in a recruitment process, but by far the most likely scenario is that the END of [date] is meant. Had a bunch of people said "Yes, I use that trick all the time", that would also have constituted a useful answer.

Comment: You're over-thinking it. Midnight has nothing to do with tricking applicants. The job posting has an expiration date. Midnight is when that day ends and the next day begins (the first day after the posting has expired). Nothing more. If you didn't get the job, don't blame the application deadline.

Comment: The way I read it this is more a question about misuse of the English language than an actual work question.  Sort of like "Please be seated as the plane will be landing momentarily".

Answer (score 5):

Regardless of what technical definition chronologists (is there such a thing?) or astronomers might have invented, most people understand "until midnight on Thursday" to mean any time on Thursday, up until the midnight that separates Thursday from Friday.

I doubt someone would use this as a tool to weed out applicants. If they did, it would be a bad idea. Even assuming that they are insisting that the "correct definition" is that "midnight Thursday" means 1 minute after 11:59 pm Wednesday:

(a) Would a clear understanding of such a technicality be relevant to the job? If it's a job involving timekeeping, maybe so. But most other jobs, no. It would be a totally irrelevant criterion. Like hiring an accountant and quizzing all applicants on the dietary requirements of frogs.

(b) If someone gets his application in before the deadline, does that mean he understood the definition? Or just that he was playing it safe and getting his application in at least a day early?  Likewise, if someone submits an application an hour after the deadline, does that mean they didn't properly interpret the deadline, or that they thought, "bummer, I missed the deadline. Well, let me send in the application anyway, maybe they won't enforce the deadline strictly." Most of the "passes" would be false positives and many of the "misses" would be false negatives.

Comment: I did once have a boss who said the release will be midnight Wednesday and actually meant come in in the transition from Tuesday to Wednesday. So it wouldn't hurt to ask and determine where your boss might mean. This should be a one time only question since it would mean going forward when "midnight" means.

Answer (score 2):

**"Midnight on *date*" by convention usually refers to the night *after* that date.**

[This question on English Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6459/how-should-midnight-on-be-interpreted) (found by Brandin) discusses this in detail.

This does slightly conflict with the fact that the next day officially starts a that moment, creating some ambiguity.  But nevertheless, the way a term is most  commonly used, even if idiosyncratic, drives its meaning.  I don't think you are warranted in assuming the start of the day is the "correct" use of midnight, and a recruiter certainly would be ill-advised to use that as a test (although, of course, somebody might do anything).

**If you are really unsure, you are always free to ask (or better yet, get your application in the previous day to avoid any doubt).**  But personally I would not worry about assuming they mean the end of that day.

Comment: Yes, easy solution is to get your application in before the earliest possible interpretation of the deadline. Then you don't have to ask. It's barely possible that the interviewer would say "what kind of idiot doesn't know that 'midnight of June 1 means ..." Or more likely, that someone would just be annoyed with a trivial question. Why make trouble for yourself?

Comment: As a sidelight, most insurance policies go into effect at "12:01 AM on {date}"  Insurance companies *hate* ambiguities...

Answer (score -1):

Midnight states 00:00 which would mean when you say:

> Applications close at midnight on [date]

It actually says: Applications till [date] - 00:00

Yes, I do think one would disregard all afterwards as you clearly lack the time management to not send it at idk 6pm the day or week before.

Lets assume you are an teacher at a regular school, you have multiple classes on different years.
A teacher needs to prepare alot of things such as:

- prepare for different classes
- schedule tests and score them
- finish certain subjects in x time
- Attend teacher Meetings
- reschedule classes
- schedule test retry's
- respond to questions asked by students

Now that might not sound like alot to everyone, but consider the deadlines you have for the different years and the meetings that keep shifting or require follow ups. If you want to do that, you really shouldnt risk sending in an simple applications on the last possible moment.

Also consider this everyone ignores the end date and keep sending applications weeks after. Now there might be people in there that might be up for the Job,
But at some point you Need to start filtering down people. When do i get to that Point? I would say the application close date.

Comment: Completely agreed that good time management is a valid requirement for many jobs, including teaching. But that doesn't answer the question of whether some recruiters use this particular method to test it.

Comment: @user2390246 "Yes, I do think one would disregard all afterwards" and then i explain why. Wether or not one recruiter would use it as you think they do is unanswerable. When they have or expect alot they might use this but that all depending on x reasons.

Comment: Sending in an application at the last minute is not evidence of poor time management.  Maybe you only just saw the job?  Maybe you are using all available time to prepare?

Comment: @dan1111 well in one side you are right, but on the other why would you look at 11:50 pm for a Job. Secondly how long does one take to write an application. Thirdly depends entirely on the Person who receives it. My teachers always said we manage our time poorly by sending in at the last Moment. So hey it might. ^^

Comment: @RaoulMensink someone who does excellent preparation for a job application might 1) research the company, role, area 2) tailor their resume to highlight skills important for that job 3) take time to write a good cover letter 4) Have someone else look over all the application materials for mistakes.  All of this takes time.  Of course many people apply at the last minute because of poor time management--but not everyone!

Comment: @dan1111 "Sending in an application at the last minute is not evidence of poor time management." It's not *proof*, but I would have thought it is *evidence*.

Comment: Various recruitment processes would need to work this way: at the end time stamp, all applications supplied would get batched up and sent to the hiring manager or HR. You need a deadline - why not midnight? It would be the same if it was 4pm or 7am.